Bad State: no ProviderScope found. I think I have placed the ProviderScope correctly
I am trying to learn riverpod, fairly new here, and I am getting this error, I don't understand why. It states the no providerScope found, but I think I placed it correctly, I rechecked and made sure I have flutter-riverpod in pubspec and not just riverpod, any help would be great.
I rechecked and made sure I have flutter-riverpod in pubspec and not just riverpod, any help would be great. I read that I should check the if ref is mounted or not, but I don't understand what it means.
This is the main.dart file
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:testing_app/riverpodTest.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: const MainApp()));
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    home: const MyTestPage()
    );
  }
}

This is where I am watching for the data to reach from the api
final userDataProvider = FutureProvider<List<UserModel>>((ref) async {
  final posts = await ref.watch(userProvider).getPosts();
  return posts;
});

This is the MyTestPage() code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:testing_app/data_provider.dart';
import './userModel.dart';

class MyTestPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyTestPage({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ref) {
    final _data = ref.watch(userDataProvider);
    return Scaffold(
        body: _data.when(
            data: (_data) {
              List<UserModel> userList = _data.map((e) => e).toList();
              return Column(children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: userList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                        color: Colors.deepPurple[200],
                        elevation: 5,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 10.0,
                        ),
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(userList[index].name),
                          subtitle: Text(userList[index].address),
                        ));
                  },
                ))
              ]);
            },
            error: (err, s) => Text(err.toString()),
            loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator()));
  }
}


Have you done a hot restart?

@DhafinRayhan Yeah I have done that, no help there.
